# Sobreescribir un json file con python

Tags: python

Tengo una función que crea un json vacío y otra que sobreescribe el contenido de dicho json, pero de la manera en que lo tengo lo sobreescribe con un solo objeto cada vez a pesar de pasarle un listado de alrededor 10. ¿Cómo puedo sobreescribir TODA la información cada vez que llame a dicha función?

```
def override_json(folder_path, elements) -> None:
    json_path = os.path.join(folder_path, 'data.json')
    try:
        with open(json_path, 'r') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        data = {}
        
    for element in elements:
        unique_key = str(datetime.now())
        data[unique_key] = element.__dict__

    with open(json_path, 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file, indent=2)
```

Esta es la función desde donde lo llamo

```
def scrap_infinite_page() -> None:
    clear_console()

    current_datetime:[datetime] = datetime.now()
    folder_path:[str] = create_folder(current_datetime)

    options:[webdriver.ChromeOptions] = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver:[webdriver.WebDriver] = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    
    index:[int] = 0
    
    page_url = INFINITE_SCROLL_URL
    driver.get(page_url)
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:    
        try:
            quotes:list[Quote] = []

            quotes_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, MAX_TIME_DELAYED).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "quote"))
            )

            for i in range(index, len(quotes_elements)):
                quote_element = quotes_elements[i]
                quote:Quote = extract_quote(quote_element)
                quotes.append(quote)

            index = len(quotes_elements)
            
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(5)
            
            new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            
            if new_height == last_height:
                break
            
            last_height = new_height

            override_json(folder_path, quotes)
            
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error al obtener los elementos:", e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu función debería funcionar bien excepto por un detalle, la precisión de `datetime.datetime.now` depende de la plataforma, por ejemplo, en mi sistema (Linux) la resolución de `datetime.datetime.now` es de 1 μs.

De la propia [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now):

> ... si es posible, suministra más precisión de la que se puede obtener
> usando una marca temporal de `time.time()` (por ejemplo, esto puede
> ser posible en plataformas que suministran la función de C
> `gettimeofday()`).

y en `time.time()` nos dice:

> Tenga en cuenta que aunque el tiempo siempre se retorna como un número
> de coma flotante, no todos los sistemas lo proporcionan con una
> precisión superior a 1 segundo.

Es muy posible que en tu sistema `datetime.datetime.now` no tenga la resolución necesaria para generar una fecha distinta entre cada iteración del `for`. Si ocurre esto, todos los items nuevos tendrán la misma clave, por lo que solo se agregara el último de ellos al diccionario `data`. Puedes ver esto simplemente imprimiendo `unique_key` en cada iteración del ciclo.

Una posible opción, manteniendo la fecha como clave, seria agregar un pequeño incremento a cada fecha generada en el `for`, por ejemplo:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# ...

for i, element in enumerate(elements):
    unique_key = str(datetime.now() + timedelta(milliseconds=i))
    data[unique_key] = element.__dict__
```

De forma que te aseguras que cada una de ellas sea diferente.